# Jquery Plugin with required CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have written a JQuery Plugin.  The plugin adds a customised view to a list (similar to JQuery Mobiles .listview()).

The idea being I can create a generic unordered list and then apply my plugin to add behaviours and styles after.

```
    <ul data-role="none">
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>

$("ul").myView();
```

What I haven't seen much of is plugins adding big chunks of css.  My plugin requires certain css classes to be available to work so where do I store them?  is it common for plugins to come with stylesheets?

Comment: YES. It's very common.  Just look at jquery ui.  Just have the user add your plugin's css files along with the js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common for plugins to come with set of predefined CSS. But IMO it should be up to the plugin-user to manually add the stylesheet into the `<head>` tag on their own before loading any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter says, it's typical for such plugins to have CSS packaged with them, but for the user to link it manually. There are a few reasons for this:

- The user may keep JS and CSS files in unusual locations, necessitating user intervention to point the include properly
- CSS is load-order dependent, so inserting it automatically may overwrite user CSS rules or prevent the user overriding plugin CSS without editing source files
- Many jQuery plugins, especially those that affect form elements and scrolling, need to gracefully degrade when JavaScript is turned off. If the CSS is added via JavaScript, the plugin author can't control degradation at all.

Automatically configuring everything is great for the end-user, but most developers will need an enhanced degree of control.